# Express generator creates pug files in view

Tags: node.js, express, npm, ejs

When creating a web application with node.js, express and the express generator, the template files in view are ending with pug. Should it not be .ajs files? Is there a way to change it?.
I am new to web development

Answer (score 2):

use express --view ejs app instead